# request uri php: get first level

Tags: php

If I had a url such as **`www.example.com/test/example/product.html`**

How would I be able to get just the test part(so the top level)

I understand you would use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and maybe `substr` or `trim`

But I am unsure of how to do this, thank you!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Split the string into an array with `explode`, and then take the part you need.

```
$whatINeed = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$whatINeed = $whatINeed[1];
```

If you use PHP 5.4, you can do `$whatINeed = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1];`

Comment: Shouldn't this be $whatINeed[1]? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] starts with a slash with the result that the first URI level is in [1] rather than [0].

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname.foo.bar/test/example/product.html?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

$urlArray = parse_url($url);

/* Output:

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /test/example/product.html
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)


*/

echo dirname($urlArray[path]);

/* Output:

/test    

*/
```

Comment: Hmm, the idea of using parse_url is ok, but the dirname will return "/text/example" - the whole dirname. It goes up only one level.

Comment: Good catch, you would either have to feed it to its self multiple times or use explode (just watch out for cross-OS issues)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to get the first part of any path is to use `strtok()`:

```
echo strtok($path, '/');
```

This will work regardless of whether or not it has a leading `/`. To do this with a url you can extract the path part with `parse_url()` and use the same `strtok()` method mentioned above like this:

```
echo strtok(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/')
```